# MySQLi prepared statements: Short versions in one line

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In PHP, I use a lot of one liners like:

Fetch value:

```
$sql->query("SELECT ID FROM table WHERE condition = 1")->fetch_object()->ID;
```

Fetch row:

```
$sql->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition = 1")->fetch_assoc();
```

Fetch rows:

```
$sql->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition > 1")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Insert row:

```
$sql->query("INSERT INTO table(`row1`,`row2`) VALUES('".$data1."','".$data2."')");
```

Delete row:

```
$sql->query("DELETE FROM table WHERE condition = 1");
```

Are there also beautiful one liners for prepared statements?

This fails:

```
$sql->prepare("SELECT ID FROM table WHERE condition = ?")->bind_param("i", $a=1)->execute()->fetch_object()->ID;
```

This works:

```
$query = $sql->prepare("SELECT ID FROM table WHERE condition = ?");
$query->bind_param("i", $a=1);
$query->execute();
$query->get_result()->fetch_object()->ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly - there is no way. But you may use a simple overlay class which will allow you to do so.

```
class PrepareOverlay {
    private $stmt;  
    private $lastResult = null;      

    public function __construct(PDOStatement $stmt) {
        $this->stmt = $stmt;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $this->lastResult = call_user_func_array([$this->stmt, $name], $arguments);
        return is_bool($this->lastResult) ? $this : $this->lastResult;
    }

    public function getLastResult() {
        return $this->lastResult;
    }

    public static function prepare($sql, $query) {
        return new self($sql->prepare($query));
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
PrepareOverlay::prepare($sql, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE cond = ?')->bindParam('i', $a=1)->execute()->fetchObject()->ID;
```

Although you will need some phpdoc to make code completion work.

Answer (score 0):

if you consider using a framework like codeigniter you will be able to enjoy the Active record class, and you will be able to use something elegant like those lines :

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');

// Produces: SELECT * FROM mytable
```

or

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);
```

or

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');

$query = $this->db->get();

// Produces:
// SELECT * FROM blogs
// JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```

you can also use chaining like this

```
$this->db->select('title')->from('mytable')->where('id', $id)->limit(10, 20);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

or

```
echo $this->db->count_all('my_table');

// Produces an integer, like 25
```

or

```
$this->db->delete('mytable', array('id' => $id));

// Produces:
// DELETE FROM mytable
// WHERE id = $id
```

and much more ... take a look at the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) for a full documentation about active record

cheers !